# Starting out with Arduino - beginner kits

Tags: arduino

I'm considering getting started with Arduino, and looked around for beginner kits. I've found 2 that particularly caught my attention

- The [Arduino Starter Kit](http://store.arduino.cc/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2&products_id=185/), in the official Arduino website;
- The [KIT Workshop PTRobotics with Arduino Uno](http://www.ptrobotics.com/kit-s/709-kit-workshop-ptrobotics-with-arduino-uno.html), in PTRobotics, found in the Arduino's Distributor's list.

Now, the second one is about 30€ cheaper, but (obviously) contains less material. So, my question is: are the extra parts in the first kit worth the extra 30€, or would it be better to save that money and later use it to buy other parts?

The way I see it, the first kit is a bit more "general", and provides a bit more freedom, but, since I've never worked with Arduino, I really can't tell if it's worth it.

I appreciate any help you might give.

---

I understand there is a (quite) subjective side to the question, but please try to remain objective: Are the parts worth it? Could I get them cheaper (without recurring to counterfeits)? Are they "worthless" for beginners?

Comment: The book is probably the big difference in price and to a lesser extent the effort to find various items at reasonable prices. Diodes cost maybe 10ct or less in volume, but if you only have a single one and you blow it ...

Comment: @jippie Considering the amount of tutorials and "getting started" guides I could find online, the book doesn't attract me that much (useful, of course, but not indispensable). What caught my eye in the first one were actually the motors (and, a bit less, the sensors) and, related to your last sentence, the greater amounts of each part (resistors, LEDs, etc), useful, if nothing else, as a "spare tire".

Answer (score 3):

Pick a project, and buy what you need to buy to accomplish it, with spares of everything for when you screw up. Repeat this for each project.  Eventually you'll build an inventory of stuff you use most. If you go with a big kit, there will still be things you'll need to order to complete a project.  It's not the cost of the components that will get you --- its the process of forming an order, paying for shipping, and waiting for what you need that will be most annoying, and then doing it again when you forget something.

Comment: This. Buy at least 1 spare of everything you need. There is nothing more irritating than needed to spend $10 in shipping on a $0.50 part.

Comment: A single 1N4148 genaral purpose low power diode costs you €0.05 at a reasonable local Dutch mail order house 10+ @ €0.03 and 100+ @ €0.02. The physical shop around the corner will probably charge me €0.20 each if not more. If you look around a bit on Internet you can find 500 for €2.25 maybe even less. I agree with Scott and @MattYoung, don't buy singles, buy small nice priced volumes, especially for general purpose parts.